# Live Stream (of some channel) Play through Roku Box

Tags: live, http-live-streaming, roku, brightscript

I were trying to join igmp live streaming and play it in roku box. But it didn't worked.
Is it that we can not join multicast streaming in Roku boxes ?
If it is possible to do via HLS, then what could be the solution ?
I tried the reference in github at link : https://github.com/thetrime/trimeplay/blob/master/source/trimeplay.brs
Please refer the another code I were using as reference :

```
function SetupJoin()
ssdpAddress = "239.60.60.7:6607"
ssdpPort = 6607
timeout = 300 * 60 * 1000
groupAddr = CreateObject("roSocketAddress")
groupAddr.setAddress(ssdpAddress)
groupAddr.setPort(ssdpPort)
listenAddr = CreateObject("roSocketAddress")
listenAddr.setPort(ssdpPort)
listenAddr.setAddress("0.0.0.0")
listen = CreateObject("roDatagramSocket")
listen.setReuseAddr(true)
listen.setAddress(listenAddr)
result = listen.joinGroup(groupAddr)
listen.setMessagePort(canvas.GetMessagePort())
listen.notifyReadable(true)
numResponses= Wait_SSDP(listen, timeout)
? "Result : " result
? "SSDP Listen got"; numResponses; " responses"
end function

function Wait_SSDP(socket as Object, timeout as Integer) as Integer
numResponses = 0
elapsed = CreateObject("roTimespan")
remaining = timeout - elapsed.totalMilliseconds()
while remaining > 0
msg = wait(remaining, socket.getMessagePort())
if type(msg)="roSocketEvent"
if socket.isReadable()
results = socket.receiveStr(255)
print "SSDP Listen gets from "; socket.getReceivedFromAddress().getAddress(); ":"
print results
numResponses = numResponses + 1
end if
else
exit while 'enter code here
end if
remaining = timeout - elapsed.totalMilliseconds()
end while
return numResponses
end function
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to say that what you are trying to do is completely impossible, but it is impractical.

You would have to do something sort of like this:

Use roStreamSockets to collect the UDP data and write it to tmp:/ as an h.264 video file, probably as HLS chunks, then point the video playback component at it via .m3u8 files you also write on the fly. This would have to be done in Brightscript. I'm not sure that Brightscript is fast enough to do this. I'm not saying it is impossible to do it, but Roku does not natively play multicast or other UDP video stream formats.

The only officially supported video formats for live broadcast are HLS and Microsoft Smooth.

Comment: wont you please add it? (play of UDP stream) pretty please